# Naming issue with AngularJS controllers

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, tabs, naming-conventions

I just started playing around with `AngularJS`. I did however stumble upon a case that had me quite puzzled, when trying to use the [angular bootstrap directives](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) for creating tabbed panes. I followed [this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/PCkokTwUEblmrREKzcvI), and the only thing I changed was renaming the `TabsCtrl` variable to `TabsController`, because I had been using *Controller convention in the rest of my application.

What I found really strange is that this renaming broke the entire thing! The `TabsController` function was never executed after the renaming. You can test it yourself on the [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/PCkokTwUEblmrREKzcvI).

I need to get this straight, as it seems scary that renaming an object like this would make it break without me knowing why. Is the *Controller variable name reserved somehow? How come I have been able to use the *Controller naming convention for the rest of my controllers without problems?

Edit: It seems that it is the exact word `TabsController` that is causing the issue. I tried naming it BajsController instead, and that worked..

Comment: your plunker example works, renaming controller will not brake anything

Comment: Yes, it works.. The problem occurs once you rename to TabsController

Comment: renaming BajsController to TabsController?

Comment: When it's called "TabsController", it does not draw the Dynamic tabs. Only the one static tab. Or is it drawing all the tabs on your computer..?

Comment: No, you are right, strange..

Comment: this error is only for tabsController, name it konichivaController for example, everything will work

Comment: maybe in bootstrap there is already controller named TabsController and that's why

Comment: Yes, I found that as well :)

Comment: Ok, good luck then :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, I found it.

It seems that the bootstrap angular directives are already defining a controller called `"TabsController"`, so that is where the conflict is.

I didn't find this conflict when I was looking for an existing object called `"TabsController"` in the debug console, but that is of course because it was not declared as a global variable inside the bootstrap directive.